# AppCode Interface Builder

Tags: interface-builder, appcode

Are there any plugins for AppCode so that I can edit and design the user interface like the Interface Builder in Xcode?

I prefer AppCode because it's customizable but it appears to me that it doesn't have its own Interface Builder.

Comment: You are prefering AppCode no doubt, however Xcode has more features than AppCode if you can use Xcode it will be more fruitful to you.

Comment: Thank you! I hope Apple will bring more customizations to Xcode in the future.

Comment: @GouravJoshi I don't think that's quite true -- each has their own strengths. Xcode is prettier and has some great iOS/macOS-specific tools (notably the Core Data Editor, Interface Builder for those who like it, nice integration with Instruments, etc). But AppCode has *far* superior code navigation, editing, generation and refactoring features. When you're used to creating code in AppCode, Xcode feels quite primitive. AppCode also has a better debugger than Xcode's.

Comment: @Cris : Where I am saying that appcode is not good or not right to use...I am shared my opinion.  If really it was a great idea then I will put this as answer not a comment.

Comment: @GouravJoshi No worries -- I'm just commenting for other readers here, to point out that Xcode and AppCode are both worth investigating. They have alternative approaches that will appeal to different people.

Comment: @GouravJoshi ... not true. By now, i only use the toy (Xcode) to play certificates.  I find rolling my own layouts by hand easier (by far) than fighting the Interface builder.

Answer (score 20):

No. JetBrains previously shipped a UI Designer plugin, but [have stopped developing it](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/objc/editing-interface-files.html).

For many projects you will be using [AppCode in parallel with Xcode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/objc/appcode-and-xcode.html). Use each for its strengths: eg. AppCode for writing code, refactoring and debugging, Xcode for Interface Builder and Core Data models. There is an AppCode command `Open Project in Xcode`, for which you can easily add a keybinding in Prefs -> Keymap

There's no real disadvantage to using AppCode with Xcode as in order to build macOS/iOS projects you need Xcode installed anyway.